# Type definition of command line arguments (argc, argv, args)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, command-line-arguments, argv, argc

I'm using C++/CLR .NET, and defining a main.

In C, I would use the normal

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) //Typical for C, works for C++
```

However, being .NET I've also seen

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args) //Managed .NET array type
```

How far can I take this? Can I place the command line arguments into nearly any structure I feel like? For example...

```
 int main(int argc, string argv[]) //More useful if I want strings anyway
 int main(vector<string> args)
```

Comment: No. You can only use the forms the hosting environment explicitly supports.

Comment: Is there any information on where/what these are?

Comment: Yes, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function).

Comment: [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88w63h9k.aspx)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious it doesn't say `main` can be defined however *we* want. Only that a hosting environment *may* provide other options

Comment: As an additional, have you tried making a simple program using `int main(int argc, string argv[])` or `int main(vector<string> args)` as the `main` function and see what the results are?

Comment: Technically, `int main(int argc, std::vector<std::string> argv) { for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) { std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl; } return 0; }` compiles and runs, but it doesn't produce what you think it would ...

Comment: @txtechhelp Have tried both my examples, and yours - they all compile and then throw an error to do with objects not being initialised. I'm guessing that would be VS15 way of saying it cant be defined that way

Comment: @davidhood2 .. the objects aren't initialized because they're essentially being casted from `char*[]` to `std::string[]` which is undefined behavior. That code will compile on just about any C++ compiler (`gcc` as well). The `main` function has a specific definition that the compiler builds out that the kernel can then call when it needs to execute, thus you're forcing the `main` function to do something that is not standard.